# Android - Display image that is of type file

Tags: java, android

I have an image that is currently stored in variable of type "File"..

```
File img = ...;
```

What is the easiest way to display this image onto the screen so I can verify it is working correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an ImageView in your layout, you can do something like this, assuming you have a reference to your ImageView named `view`:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(img);
image.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Seems simple enough, except I am getting an error that createFromPath requires an argument of type String instead of type File.. Is it expecting the path of the file? I attempted to try img.getAbsolutePath() but it crashed.

Comment: :) Nevermind, I figured out that I had a whole different problem.. My img variable is not getting initialized correctly.

Thanks!